# Powershell extract Year and month from string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to accomplish a script that will allow to loop through folder and files.

1. The script will import a file and extract the Name and Number from the file.
2. Using the Name loop through `C:\Temp` folders to find that name.
3. List all the files under that folder and extract the Year and Month. The file looks like below and the script extract `201705` from the file name and convert the `05` month to `May`
   `AAA_123456789_201705021541_AAAAAA.pdf`
4. The script then takes any files that are `May`, `June`, `July` etc and send them to a different folder by creating a folder using the Number from the imported file. So for example if the filename has `05` in it the folder `X00000000MAY2017` and the files MAY files moved to that folder.

The have got the below script so far. I am able to import files extract the info and loop through it but getting stuck at the part to extract month and year from the filename and put them in variable.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path  C:\temp\test.txt -Header "Number","Name" -Delimiter "|"
$Name = $data.Name

foreach ($cxName in $Name) {
    $cxName = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\$cxName

    ForEach ($item in $cxName) {
        If ($item -match "(?<year>\d\d\d\d)(?<mon>\d\d)") {
            "$item's date is $($Matches.Year)"
        } Else {
            "$item failed to match"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know where the date is going to be in that file name string? I am a little lost on how step 4 works as well. So the matched date will have a corresponding folder that ends in MonYYYY that you have to look for?

Comment: I assume your regex kind of works but `$Matches.Year` will output "1234" in your file name example? Is there any way you can be sure that your date will be always in the same place? Or do you have some kind of reference?

Comment: `[datetime]::parseexact($item.name.split('_')[2].substring(0,6),'yyyyMM',$null)` should give you a `[datetime]` object. Then just use `ToString('MMMyyyy')` to reformat it.

Comment: PS: In your specific example `$item -match ".*_.*_(?<year>\d\d\d\d)(?<mon>\d\d)"` will work, but if the position of the date isn't always after 2 "_"s, it won't match anymore.

Comment: @Matt It should. `$cxName` is the result of `Get-ChildItem`, so it should be a collection of `[directoryinfo]` and `[fileinfo]` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this into a function call from your get-childitem

```
Param(
[string]$subject = "AAA_123456789_201705021541_AAAAAA.pdf"
)
Clear-Host

if ($subject -imatch '_([2-9][0-9]{3})(\d{2})') {
$Year   = $matches[1]
$Month  = $matches[2]
$Month = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($Month)
Write-Host "Extracted:`n$Month,$Year"
} else {
Write-Error "No Matches were found dog"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$folder_name='201705';
$year_month = [datetime]::ParseExact($folder_name, "yyyyMM", $null);
$year_month;
```

If yes, please use it, else please ask exact requirement instead of such long question. I hope this helps